# Instantiate generic interface that has generic property

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to refactor a very specific code to make it more generic, so we can expand the use case, but I'm struggling when dealing with generic types. The code in question is (just adding the signature and the parts I need help):

```
public class Data { }

public class PersonData : Data { }

public interface IDataSchema<T> where T : Data { }

public class PersonEntityProvider
{
    public IDataSchema<PersonData> PersonSchema { get; }
}

public class EntityManager
{
    private PersonEntityProvider personEntityProvider;

    public PersonEntityProvider PersonEntityProvider => personEntityProvider = new PersonEntityProvider();
}
```

What exactly I'm trying to do is make the `EntityManager` class accept multiple `EntityProviders`, via a factory pattern. `EntityProviders` requires to have a schema, defined by IDataSchema, that uses an underlying class that represents the data.

So what I tried to do was to make `EntityManager` depend on abstraction of `EntityProviders`:

```
public interface IEntityProvider<T> where T : Data
{
    IDataSchema<T> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class PersonEntityProvider : IEntityProvider<PersonData>
{
    public IDataSchema<PersonData> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class EntityManager
{
    private IEntityProvider<Data> entityProvider;

    public IEntityProvider<Data> EntityProvider =>
        entityProvider = new PersonEntityProvider();
}
```

But when I try to instantiate the provider, the compiler tells me that I cannot convert `PersonEntityProvider` to `IEntityProvider<Data>`. I thought it was going to work because PersonData is derivable from Data, but apparently doesn't work. I also thought in make EntityManager generic, but that would require too much changes in pieces I don't wanna touch right now... So I tried to change the interface to make it not be generic:

```
public interface IEntityProvider
{
    IDataSchema<Data> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class PersonEntityProvider : IEntityProvider
{
    public IDataSchema<PersonData> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class EntityManager
{
    private IEntityProvider entityProvider;

    public IEntityProvider EntityProvider => entityProvider = new PersonEntityProvider();
}
```

Doesn't work as well, this time it tells me that my `PersonEntityProvider` does not follow the interface contract because the type of `IDataSchema` needs to be `Data`, instead of `PersonData`.

I feel like I'm missing something, but I'm stuck on this for a few hours. What do you think?

Comment: Add an `IData` interface that `Data` must implement and use `IData` everywhere you used `Data` in your code and it should work and the casting issue won't be a problem anymore. Because technically, `PersonData` isn't the same type as `Data` even though it inherits from it... so they can't be used interchangeably because they are different. Ony interfaces can be used as types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, `PersonData` inherits from `Data`, When they are used `Data` isn't `PersonalData` they share properties since one is the inheriter.

Here's your problem:

```
public class EntityManager
{
    private IEntityProvider<Data> entityProvider;

    public IEntityProvider<Data> EntityProvider =>
        entityProvider = new PersonEntityProvider();
}
```

Here, your `entityProvider` and `EntityProvider` method are of type `IEntityProvider<Data>` not `IEntityProvider<PersonData>`... So the issue is with casting.

---

**The solution**

```
public interface IData { }

public class Data : IData { }

public class PersonData : Data { }

public interface IDataSchema<T> where T : IData { }

public interface IEntityProvider<T> where T : IData
{
    IDataSchema<T> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class PersonEntityProvider : IEntityProvider<IData>
{
    public IDataSchema<IData> DataSchema { get; }
}

public class EntityManager
{
    private IEntityProvider<IData> entityProvider;

    public IEntityProvider<IData> EntityProvider =>
        entityProvider = new PersonEntityProvider();
}
```

Here, you declare a new interface `IData` which `Data` implements. Then, `PersonData` inherits from `Data`. Remember, to ensure that things are generic, keep types as interfaces not classes ... like you did in your question using `Data` as the defining type. So,  you can use `IData` whereever you have `PersonData` or `Data` classes as return types like you see on my suggested code. I have checked my suggested code on VS and it works.

Comment: This didn't work too... Suppose I receive the IDataSchema via a constructor parameter: `PersonEntityProvider(IDataSchema<IData> dataSchema)`. And I have a schema defined this way: `class PersonDataSchema : IDataSchema<PersonData> {}`. When I try to instantiate the Provider passing this schema: `IEntityProvider<IData> provider = new PersonEntityProvider(new PersonDataSchema());` it tells me that I cannot convert `PersonDataSchema` to `IDataSchema<IData>`. Maybe this is a sign that I reached a dead end and need to redesign this part of the code.

Comment: It should be `public class PersonDataSchema : IDataSchema<IData> { }` always the idea is to program against the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: You declare a variable using Interface as type, but you instantiate the implementation...

Comment: You can't interchange `PersonData` with `IData`, `PersonData` implements `IDataSchema<IData>` not `IData`. That is why you encounter a casting exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps make the type parameters of your *IDataSchema<T>* and *IEntityProvider<T>* interfaces [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) (in essence, the same way [IEnumerable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) is declared):

```
public interface IDataSchema<out T>  where T : Data {}

public interface IEntityProvider<out T> where T : Data
{
    IDataSchema<T> DataSchema { get; }
}
```

(Note the `out` keyword annotating the generic type parameter.)

Using covariant type parameters however incurs some restrictions on the interfaces:

- Properties being of a covariant generic type parameter type cannot have a setter declared by the interface.
- Arguments of methods declared by the interface cannot use covariant generic type parameters (the return type of a method can still be a covariant generic type parameter).

Comment: Having tried this on VS. It doesn't solve the casting issue that he encountered when instantiating the `PersonEntityProvider`.

Comment: Yeah, like you mentioned, the restrictions block me because `IDataSchema` defines some methods that use the generic type as parameters to output another type. Maybe I'll need to redesign this part of entities because it sounds like a dead end.